# `_gfortran_os_error_at could not be located in the dynamic link library` with allocatable variable using MSYS2

Tags: dll, fortran, gfortran, msys2

I am having this strange error when compiling a simple code using msys2:

```
The procedure entry point _gfortran_os_error_at could not be located in the dynamic link library
```

Other compiler implementations work fine.

Here is the code:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: N
REAL(8), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:) :: X
N = 10
ALLOCATE(X(N,N))
DEALLOCATE(X)
END PROGRAM MAIN
```

> The compiler is GNU Fortran (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0

The compiling method is

```
gfortran -o main.exe main.f90
```

I noticed that when I link the program with `-static` it surprisingly works. I am not sure if this is a common problem with gfortran compilers.

Comment: You should really mention your compiler version, the exact compilation and the exact linking command.

Comment: A hunch: you might be compiling with one version of the gfortran runtime library, and finding a different version at runtime.